# Devise Gem Ruby On Rails - Removing "Cancel my account" for admins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to remove the "cancel my account" option for the admin account whilst using the devise gem.

app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb:

```
 <% if current_user && current_user.admin? %>
 <h3>Cancel my account</h3>

 <p>Unhappy? <%= button_to "Cancel my account",     registration_path(resource_name), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method:  :delete %></p>
```

This gets rid of the "cancel my account" for the usual user but still keeps it for the admin. However, I would like it the other way round so it views for the user and not the admin.

[Cancel My Account - User View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fLq3.png)

[Cancel My Account - Admin View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zyq8V.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% if current_user && !current_user.admin? %>
```

The negation `!` will return the opposite value.  So `!current_user.admin?` is the opposite of `current_user.admin?`

Comment: thank you so much!! That worked. I amended it so it is `<% if current_user && !current_user.admin? %>`